# Are methods also objects like functions are?

Tags: function, object, dart, methods

I read that functions (AKA static methods) are objects (instances of the `Function` class). Are methods (instance functions) also objects? I can't find the answer in the official documentation. It only says functions are objects (but doesn't explain if all functions are, including methods).

Comment: This is stated the [dart tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts): `Everything you can place in a variable is an object, and every object is an instance of a class. Even numbers, functions, and null are objects. All objects inherit from the Object class`

Comment: I remember reading that but I didn't think you could place a method (a part of an object) in a variable. I thought probably only the entire object containing the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy to verify that the method is an object:

```dart
class Foo {
  bar() {}
}

void main() {
  print(Foo().bar is Object); // prints true
}
```

and linter shows a warning:

> Unnecessary type check, the result is always true

Comment: I don't have an IDE set up for coding in Dart yet. Was just watching tutorials and reading the docs to research if this is the right language for my purposes. I also think this question should have an explicit answer (at least on SO, if not in the official docs). So thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the answer is "no". In practice, that never matters.

Instance methods are properties of classes that can be invoked via objects that are instances of those classes. A method is not itself a *value*, so it makes not sense to ask if it's an object, because all objects are values. You can refer to a method by name (it's "denotable"), but that's it. You cannot evaluate an expression to a method or store it in a variable.

*However*, you can *tear off* an instance method from an object. When you do that, a *new* function object is created which, when called, will invoke the method on the original object with the same arguments.
That function object is, well, both a function and an object. It is not the method itself, though, if one is being pedantic.

In practice, if you ever care to ask if something is an object, it's likely already a value, and then that thing *is* an object.

(Static methods are also technically not objects, but they are *so close* to the function object created when you tear them off, that the distinction is never practically significant. The language semantics differentiates because when you create an object, it matters which object it is - what is it equal to and identical to - and until you creates a value, the language prefers to just not have to specify that.)